# Why a point light not cast shadow on my moving object, but only on static?

Tags: unity, lighting

In my Unity3d scene i've two light: a directional (sun, outside the window) and a point light. 
In my scene, I can see shadow correctly, also if i "play" with settings like Intensity or Range. 
But in Play mode, my moving player don't cast shadow when hitted by my point light, but cast shadow  correclty when hitted by directional light.

The image here is explicative: the shadow you see is from a chair, hitted by the point light. 
My player instead, hasn't shadow.

What am i wrong ?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looking at the jagged edge of the other shadow, it might just be because the character is too small to cast anything at that resolution. Does anything change if you turn up the shadow resolution in the quality settings or if you make the character bigger?